# I want to directory upload with jmeter

Tags: testing, file-upload, jmeter, load-testing

I m doing files upload with jmeter very well. But ı want to upload from directory but it is not work.
For example ı try to like this :

```
------aiYHC13zS69CLqZX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Actress/tatiana maslany/30_612x344_tatiana_maslany_sarah_orphanblack.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

But jmeter comment :

```
------aiYHC13zS69CLqZX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="_tatiana_maslany_sarah_orphanblack.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

In the absolute majority of cases you should not be building your request manually, you should do the following:

1. Tick `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box in the [HTTP Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. Switch to `Files Upload` tab
3. Provide either relative to current JMeter's working directory or full path to the file being uploaded as "File Path", use `file` as "Parameter name" and `image/jpeg` as the "MIME Type"

   [image: JMeter File Upload]

Also be aware that the fastest and the easiest way to create the proper file upload request is just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). Just make sure you have your `_tatiana_maslany_sarah_orphanblack.jpg` file copied to JMeter's "bin" folder during recording. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.